# Supervise InputStream of a Spawned Process

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to spawn the following bash script and capture its stdout asynchronously:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2;
echo "one";
sleep 2;
echo "two";
sleep 2;
echo "three";
# ... possibly infinite..
```

Here is the Java Code so far:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sleeper");
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream input = process.getInputStream();

// now I continue in pseudo-code:

supervise the input-stream.
whenever a new line arrives:
    check if the line equals "two";
       then: doSomeAction();
```

Note: I'm not actually writing the program in Java. I'm writing it in Clojure, but I haven't found a Clojure approach to do so yet. So I'm trying to use the Java native API wrapped by Clojure.

---

**a nodejs example**

Tho clarify my intention a bit more, here's a JavaScript Code for Node.JS, that does exactly, what I want:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const sleeper = spawn('sleeper');

sleeper.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  if (data.toString() === "two\n") {
      doSomeAction();
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want the input stream processing done in a separate thread and be controlled from another thread? Or it should just handle the process until it gets a specific data or the process terminates?

Comment: No, as far as I can judge that, a separate thread is not necessary. The subprocess ("sleeper") is not a heavy computing application. It's actually a unix tool that runs a small server, so it really runs infinitely. Important for my application is however, that it's not blocked while supervising the sub-process.  Everything else should go on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tools in [clojure.java.io](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html) together with straightforward Java interop.

Here’s some code to get you started:

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.io :refer [reader]])

(let [process (.start (ProcessBuilder. ["./sleeper"]))]
  (with-open [r (reader (.getInputStream process))]
    (doseq [line (line-seq r)]
      (when (= line "two")
        (println line)))))
```

Paste this into your REPL and you should see `two` being output after the appropriate delay.

Comment: You could also wrap it into a `future` so your main application thread is not blocked and can continue executing.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl Right. – I just noticed that the question asks for a solution that doesn’t block the main thread. I feel like I cannot answer that without knowing what the program does in the main thread … good luck!

Comment: even though it looks still like magic to me. I didn't know that lazy sequences can be asynchronous like this...

Comment: @AntonHarald What do you mean? Lazy sequences are not asynchronous.